# Sending files back and forth with nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, rest

I have asked and searched for this in multiple places but couldn't find any answer. So,
I have an express server that implements `Rest` methodologies. My clients can send and receive their data and all but I want them to be able to send files as well and the server should send the file back to the client on demand. From JavaScript I can use `formData` but I want to know or learn the correct way of doing it. One of them is a base64 string. Can anyone provide me a simple back and forth example of sending file back and forth in a Rest environment? Or lead me to it? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you look for tutorials on how to upload files to an `express` servers and how to download files from it - there are plenty of them out there. If you're still running into issues, come back and show us your code so that we can help you better.

Comment: about how to send REST request, I say we have no REST request, REST is just a design that accepts get, post, put, del requests. so you work as you do without RESTful design

Comment: Thanks. I am already using this method. Really appreciate you walking the extra mile to post it. I currently send the  file url as a response let the front end deal with it. Is that an acceptable practice?

Comment: the main reason of asking this question was to understand content type header. Like when can I actually use content header.

Comment: sometimes in cases that your static files doesn't need protection and authorization, it's ok to do that.(like a cooking class site) but when it matters to protect your files, you get to know how to do it. if you just try to deepen your knowledge in a specific part, you'll end up 80 years old and you'll just know how to do protection:)
don't worry.

Comment: Thanks mate! really appreciate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about how to send a REST request, I say we have no REST request, REST is just a design that accepts  get, post, put, del requests. so you work as you do without RESTful design

you can use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) that is optimized for uploading files.

first define an upload helper using multer:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const fs = require('fs');

const getDirImage = () => {
    let year = new Date().getFullYear();
    let month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
    let day = new Date().getDay();
    return `${config.homedir}/public_html/uploads/images/${year}/${month}/${day}`;
};
const ImageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        let dir;
        if (file.mimetype === 'text/css') {
            dir = getDirCss();
        } else {
            dir = getDirImage();
        }
        mkdirp(dir, (err) => cb(null, dir))
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        let filePath;
        if (file.mimetype === 'text/css') {
            filePath = getDirCss() + '/' + file.originalname;
        } else {
            filePath = getDirImage() + '/' + file.originalname;
        }

        if (!fs.existsSync(filePath))
            cb(null, file.originalname);
        else
            cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);

    }
});
const uploadImage = multer({
    storage: ImageStorage,
    limits: {
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10
    }
});
module.exports = uploadImage;
```

in your route file:

```
const upload = require('path/to/upload/helper');
router.post('/imageUpload', upload.single('image'), imageValidator.handle(), imageController.update);
```

then you can access your uploaded file in `req.file`

about returning iamge back to user you can return its url on your upload folder so they can get it; but for that you need to serve static files:

```
app.use(express.static('your_upload_dir'));
```

now you can access static files on:

`your_url/file's_location`

or: `localhost:your_app_port/file's location`

if you are testing on localhost

if you want to limit access to those files, you can use a middleware to check user's token or IP or something else. hard part would be creating a model to store file's name and url and a route for asking for files by their name.

Comment: I use ```multe```r. I was thinking about how so send the file to my server as a rest request and vice-versa.

Comment: I had another question. So, In this method I would still have to use FormData. Any way I can post a file without formData?

Comment: I don't know how to pass links in comments, please search the phrase `express how to send file without form data` in google and try them.

Comment: Thats the first thing I tried. Found nothing much to speak of :(

Comment: then sorry, I'm a newbie too. I've learnt express js in 4 months

Comment: No worries mate. I don't understand the issue. If I send the file object with fetch it doesn't parse it. Not sure how the whole file posting works really.